# Use apache mod_expires to cache php, what is a mime type for php files?

Tags: php, apache, mime-types, mod-expires

I want to cache php for few seconds in mod_expires, I can't find examples, nobody want to cache it (I know, I know).

What should I put into ExpiresByType to cache php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debian uses `text/x-php`. https://packages.debian.org/sid/mime-support

The IANA suggests `text/x-php` or `application/x-php`. https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4329.txt

Please note that `text/php` or `application/php` probably won't work.

Answer (score 0):

> What should I put into ExpiresByType to cache php?

Whatever Content-Type your PHP scripts are generating. `text/html` if they're generating HTML pages, for instance.

A better option is usually to generate Expires headers in PHP code.